# GET() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, rest, web.py

I have a web.py application with following server code.

```
import web
import mod1

urls = (
  '/(\w*)/(c|r|u|d)/(.*)', '\\1.\\2',
)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

`mod1.py` contains

```
class c:
    def POST(self):
        return "C"

class d:
    def DELETE(self):
        return "d"

class u:
    def POST(self):
        return "u"

class r:
    def GET(self, _id):
        return "v={0}".format(_id)
```

Now requesting `http://.../mod1/r/3` returns `GET() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL configuration has *3* parameters (`(\w*)`, `(c|r|u|d)` and `(.*)`). Plus the `self` argument for methods, that makes 4 arguments.

Adjust your `GET` method to accept all parameters:

```
def GET(self, param1, operation, id_):
```

These match each of the regular expression capturing groups; I guessed at the parameter names for each, you can adjust as needed.

Comment: But in [tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) it says, "`\1` is replaced by the first capture of your regular expression; any **remaining** captures get passed to your function."

Comment: [This page](http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling) makes no mention of it and there doesn't appear to be any more information on this. To be frank, I don't use `web.py` myself. It could be the tutorial is incorrect. :-)

Comment: @GenghisKhan: A quick scan of the [delegation code](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/application.py#L430) shows no such group removal. Will look a bit further, but so far it looks like the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: The tutorials are a little bit outdated. In the web.py mailing list we have discussed to re-write them, but the efforts are right now on Python 3 support.